# How to use a script to copy conditional formatting rules from one sheet to another?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-conditionalformatting

I'm trying to copy conditional formatting rules from one of my sheets to others, in Google Sheets. I know, I can just copy and use "paste special" to copy/paste them in, but I specifically want to use a script, because I've set up a script that automatically creates a new sheet, and I want to apply the conditional formatting to all of the sheets I make, because the whole spreadsheet is a sort of log, and the specific column that contains the conditional formatting applies to the entire sheet. Here's what I have:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Personally, I think the best way to get formatting into your spreadsheets is to create a spreadsheet edit it the way you want and then use it as a template to create the rest.

Answer (score 3):

Using the SpreadsheetApp [functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) and [ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder) class, you can create new rules from the rules in your sheet and insert them in the new sheet. I create the below code which works for getting all the rules from 'Merkler' sheet and insert them in 'New sheet', only if those rules are applied to the 'F' column.

```
function copyFormat() {
  //Get the Spreadsheet where the Merkler and new sheet are in
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[SPREADSHEET-ID]");
  //The source sheet with the formatting in column F is called Merkler
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("Merkler");
  //The target sheet is called "New Sheet"
  var newSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("New sheet");
  
  //The formatting will be taken from column F and copy to it in new Sheet
  var range = newSheet.getRange("F2:F1000");
  var column = 6; //F is the 6th column

  //Get all Sheet rules and iterate through them
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  var newRules = [];
  
  for(var r = 0; r < rules.length; r++) {
    var rule = rules[r];
    //Get condition for each rule
    var booleanCondition = rule.getBooleanCondition();

    //Get the ranges to which each rule applies and iterate through
    var ranges = rule.getRanges();
    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
      var ruleColumn = ranges[i].getColumn();  

      //If condition isn't null and edited column is the same as the one in the range, add rule
      if((ruleColumn == column) && (booleanCondition != null)) {
        var newRule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
        .withCriteria(booleanCondition.getCriteriaType(), booleanCondition.getCriteriaValues())
        .setBackground(booleanCondition.getBackground())
        .setRanges([range])
        .build();
        newRules.push(newRule);
      }
    }
  }
  newSheet.setConditionalFormatRules(newRules);
}
```

You need to replace the SpreadsheetID.

Comment: I also have a script attached to a button on a different page that automatically makes a new sheet, how would I have to change your code to work for mine?

[Screenshot](https://photos.app.goo.gl/WuUBSG2VUCpw6SRFA)

Comment: Add the copyFormat function to the script and replace the [Spreadsheet-ID]. Read how to run functions in Apps Script https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview

Comment: so I don't need to change anything in my script, just paste it in and change the ID, and everything will work right?

Comment: I made a copy of my spreadsheet, changed the ID, and tested it out, it still made the sheet, but not the conditional formatting.

Comment: You need to run copyFormat function after creating the new sheet. Also, check the comments I added in the code to understand what it's doing.

Comment: @Andres_Duarte Is there any way to do it just automatically? All I want is to have some code that copies the conditional formatting from a sheet and pastes those conditional formatting rules in the new sheet, and I already have a script that makes a new sheet.

Comment: Use copyFormat function at the end of your "script that makes a new sheet". Hint: you need to pass the spreadsheet-id as parameter to copyFormat function.

Comment: It doesn't work. It still makes a new sheet, but it doesn't add conditional formatting. [screenshot](https://photos.app.goo.gl/hxtaJVKxmxmXr4F4A)

Comment: I tested out and worked successfully copying the rules on F column from "Merkler" sheet to "New sheet" in the same Spreadsheet. Don't know what you might be doing different sorry, debug the code and check the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

```
    function passConditionalFormat(sourceSheetName, targetSheetName) {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      //The source of data formatting rules
      var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
      var range = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1, sourceSheet.getMaxRows(), sourceSheet.getMaxColumns());
      //The target of data formatting rules
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
      
      range.copyFormatToRange(targetSheet, 1, sourceSheet.getMaxColumns(), 1, sourceSheet.getMaxRows());
    }
```

You can use one of the following options:

1. [`copyFormatToRange(sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyformattorangesheet,-column,-columnend,-row,-rowend)
2. [`copyFormatToRange(gridId, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyformattorangegridid,-column,-columnend,-row,-rowend)

Note that this solution is good only for passing the conditional format from one sheet to another one **in the same spreadsheet**.

Comment: Avkeren, please provide some context for the usage of the method and its signatures (hovewer obvious it may be), a sample others could use would also be a nice addition, it will help in the post be positively received (especially since new answrs to old questions get into the queue for peer review) Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, Avkeren! Please flag the previous comment as no longer needed to reduce cluttering. One small note - please do not add snippets that cannot be run in current environment, a code fence will do just fine. Regardless - thank you for updating the answer!

Comment: I would have expected that `copyTo()` with `PASTE_CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING` (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed) would do the trick. Unfortunately, instead of only pasting the rules as it should - it seems to delete all values and regular formatting from the destination range...